# I parsed data into a ListView, how do I now add images to the left of each row? (From drawable folder)

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview, imageview

The listview collects data from an ArrayList that has collected it from JSON, URL and parsed it.

Now I want to add icons to the left of each row but they are local, so in my drawable folder. They don't need to be parsed. I put a link in the ViewHolder that links to the ImageView and if I go to my xml layout I can android:src=@drawable/ic_launcher and it will work. I want 10 different images though.

See my ListView below:

```
class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<idData> {

    FancyAdapter() {
        super(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfBooks);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_full, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayOfBooks.get(position));
        return(convertView);

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView id = null;
        public TextView title = null;
        public TextView link = null;
        public ImageView image = null;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);
            title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            link = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.link); 
            image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        void populateFrom(idData r) {
            id.setText("ID: " + r.id);
            title.setText(r.title);
            link.setText("URL: " + r.link);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding this to see if I could link it but it didn't work:

```
public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.ic_action_overflow,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.bg_main, R.drawable.ic_launcher};
```

Any ideas? Local images on the side of server side JSON

Any help is appreciated it.

Comment: have you tried `image.setImageResource(images[position]);` ?

Comment: no, it doesn't looks messy

Comment: @Selvin agreed i got confused coz op initializes view in his ViewHolder class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `LayoutInfalter` in your Adapter constructor. You can pass the array to the constructor and use the same in `getView`

In your constructor

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
Integer[] images = { R.drawable.ic_action_overflow,
R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.bg_main, R.drawable.ic_launcher}
FancyAdapter() {
    super(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfBooks);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ActivityContext); 
 }
```

You need to change your getview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_full, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.link = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.link);
        holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageVIew);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
     holder.id.setText("id");
     holder.title.setText("title");
     holder.link.setText("link");
     // set image to imageview 
     holder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);
     // considering you have array of drawables in images 
    return convertView ;

}
static class ViewHolder
{
 TextView id,title,link;
 ImageView image;
}
```

Edit:

Your getView implementation looks fine. I got confused at the first look. But there is no need to initialize the LayoutInflater in `getView`. Initialize the same in constructor of the adapter.

And as prosperk suggested use this `image.setImageResource(images[position])`

Comment: I modified it slightly but it worked, thanks! I kept my ViewHolder and populateFrom() and essentially just put the imageView in the getView and then the line you have, holder.image.setImageResource etc. Thanks again!

Comment: @RED_ 1 suggestioin initialize your LayoutInflater inflate outside getView in the constructor of adapter class

Comment: Ok done that, is there a big benefit for doing this? Just so the entire method gets access to it?

Comment: `getView` gets called multiple times. So you can initialize the inflater once. So initialize in the cnstructor